# Rabbit Hole redirects not working for admin

Tags: 8, nodes, redirection

I have a problem with Rabbit Hole redirects. I've set rabbit hole redirect for a content type, saved it, cleared cache. The problem is that the redirects work only for anonymous users. When I am logged as user with admin permissions, rabbit hole redirects not work.

I was searching in the Internet, in admin panel (permissions), etc, but with no results.

I also tried to set "Access denied", "Page not found" for that content type - but it's still the same. Works for anonymous users, not for admin.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Generally speaking, the permissions for the admin user will override settings that attempt to deny access because of permissions like **administer content**.  Check to see if the redirect works with an authenticated non-admin user.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Redirects work with authenticated non-admin users. So there's no way to make rabbit hole redirects work for admin?

Comment: What do you mean by "work for admin"?  Usually, you cannot give the admin a fake "page not found" or "access denied" message because that doesn't make sense (the admin generally has permission to access everything on the site).  You may be able to limit the admin permissions for the administrator role to get the behavior you expect.  To test this, do NOT use the user 1 account, as it has special permissions.  You will have to create an additional admin account and test with that.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Ok, thank you :)